# all element and sequence element

Tags: xml, xsd, sequence

How to connect the (all) element with the above (sequence) element ? or it is already connected together ?
we have done them separately because it's invalid to put (sequence) and (all) together in same element(caseif).

Here is the schema :

```
<xs:element name="caseif">   
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element ref="condition" minOccurs="1" /> 
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType>
<xs:all>
<xs:element ref="send"/>
<xs:element ref="call"/>
<xs:element ref="variable"/>
<xs:element ref="input"/>
<xs:element ref="output"/>
<xs:element ref="file"/>
<xs:element ref="comment"/>
<xs:element ref="loop"/>
<xs:element ref="case"/>
<xs:element ref="assignment"/>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Can you describe (preferably with some examples) what kinds of XML you want to consider valid and invalid?

Comment: I want in the [condition] element to be the first element to occur and then all the others elements (send, call , etc..) to occur once or none .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest design here is to put the send, call, etc. elements into a wrapper.  Then the declarations can take the form

```
<complexType name="caseif">
  <sequence>
    <element ref="tns:condition"/>
    <element ref="tns:then"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="wrapper">
  <all>
    <element ref="send" minOccurs="1"/>
    <element ref="call" minOccurs="1"/>
    <element ref="variable" minOccurs="1"/>
    ...
    <element ref="assignment" minOccurs="1"/>
  </all>
</complexType>
<element name="caseif" type="tns:caseif"/>
<element name="condition" type="tns:..."/>
<element name="then" type="tns:wrapper"/>
```

An alternative is to fix a sequence for send, call, etc.  If the order in which they appear conveys information, fixing an order is impossible. If it doesn't, fixing an order helps ensure no one thinks it does convey any information.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped :)
But what is a wrapper do exactly ?